# No mod-mono.so or mod_mono.conf after Install

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, apache-2.4, mono

(I apologize in advance for "spam" I asked on "Ask Ubuntu" but no one answered in 5 days.  I didn't think this would be hard as I'm sure many have installed Mono with Webmin on Ubuntu 12.04.)

On Ubuntu 12.04, I have webmin and apache2. With webmin, I did apt-get install mono-complete and everything appeared to install fine. I put the line "MonoAutoApplication enabled" in httpd.conf and restarted apache2, but it failes with "Invalid command 'MonoAutoApplication', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration"

All the posts I've read speak of mod-mono.so and mod_mono.conf, but I don't seem to have them.

I tried to find the module or config file

```
# find / -name "*.so" | grep -i mono
/usr/lib/libmono-profiler-iomap.so
/usr/lib/libmono-profiler-aot.so
/usr/lib/libmono-profiler-cov.so
/usr/lib/libmono-profiler-log.so
/usr/lib/libmono-2.0.so
/usr/lib/libMonoPosixHelper.so
/usr/lib/libMonoSupportW.so

# find / -name "*.conf" | grep -i mono
/etc/fonts/conf.avail/53-monospace-lcd-filter.conf
/etc/fonts/conf.d/53-monospace-lcd-filter.conf
```

I'm sure I'm missing something here, but no clue what it is. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ModMono

```
 apt-get install libapache2-mod-mono mono-apache-server2
 apt-get mono-devel
 a2enmod mod_mono_auto
 /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

The above commands are for ASP.NET 2.0 AutoHosting.

Comment: Thanks, Deer Hunter.  Should I use Webmin to uninstall my existing apache2 and the mono-complete installed via Webmin?